# Highcharts - parse json series

Tags: php, json, highcharts

Im using this to draw column highcharts [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WLRuj/)
i use this to gt JSON:

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT
                                sales_raport_all.from_date,
                                sales_raport_all.to_date,
                                sales_raport_all.konto,
                                SUM(sales_raport_all.saldo_sprzedazy),
                                SUM(sales_raport_all.wartosc_kosztowa),
                                SUM(sales_raport_all.marza),
                                klienci_ax_all.sales_group,
                                klienci_ax_all.nazwa
                            FROM
                                sales_raport_all
                            INNER JOIN
                                klienci_ax_all
                            ON
                                sales_raport_all.konto=klienci_ax_all.konto_odbiorcy
                            WHERE
                                YEAR(from_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
                            GROUP BY
                                sales_raport_all.from_date,
klienci_ax_all.sales_group
                            ORDER BY
                                sales_raport_all.from_date,
klienci_ax_all.sales_group");

$raw = array();
$dates = array();
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$date = $r['from_date'];
if (!in_array($date, $dates)) $dates[] = $date;
$sales_group = $r['sales_group'];
$raw[$sales_group][$date] = intval($r['SUM(sales_raport_all.saldo_sprzedazy)']);
}
$data = array();
$data[0] = array('name' => "Date", 'data' => $dates);
foreach ($raw as $name => $d) {
$new_data = array('name' => $name, 'data' => array());
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $new_data['data'][] = isset($d[$date]) ? $d[$date] : 0;
}
$data[] = $new_data;
}

print json_encode($data);
```

in fiddle i use

```
chart3Options.series[0] = json[1];
...
```

is there a simple way to define all data in json? this data is variable and if i declare 11 variables and there will be only 7 then charts will not draw
JSON output for one date:

```
[{"name":"Date","data":["2014-01-01"]},{"name":"IN","data":[2580]},{"name":"KD","data":[5030]},{"name":"\u0141S","data":[12628]},{"name":"NN","data":[400]},{"name":"SG","data":[12979]},{"name":"TD","data":[15096]}]
```

**// EDIT**

i create new file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'column',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'test',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: []
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'test'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: []
            }

            $.getJSON("test2.php", function(json) {
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['category'];
                options.series[0] = {};
                options.series[0].name = json[0]['name'];
                options.series[0].data = json[0]['data'];
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
        });
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and **test2.php**

```
<?php
        $db_host        = '******';
        $db_user        = '******';
        $db_pass        = '******';
        $db_database        = '******';

        $link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die('Nawiązanie połączenia z bazą danych nie było możliwe');

        mysql_select_db($db_database,$link);
        mysql_query("SET names UTF8");

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT
                                    sales_raport_all.from_date,
                                    sales_raport_all.to_date,
                                    sales_raport_all.konto,
                                    SUM(sales_raport_all.saldo_sprzedazy),
                                    SUM(sales_raport_all.wartosc_kosztowa),
                                    SUM(sales_raport_all.marza),
                                    klienci_ax_all.sales_group,
                                    klienci_ax_all.nazwa
                                FROM
                                    sales_raport_all
                                INNER JOIN
                                    klienci_ax_all
                                ON
                                    sales_raport_all.konto=klienci_ax_all.konto_odbiorcy
                                WHERE
                                    YEAR(from_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
                                GROUP BY
                                    sales_raport_all.from_date,
    klienci_ax_all.sales_group
                                ORDER BY
                                    sales_raport_all.from_date,
    klienci_ax_all.sales_group");


$result = array();



while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
     $grupa = $r['sales_group'];
     $datetime = $r['from_date'];
     $result['name'][] = $datetime;
     $result['category'][] = $grupa;
     $result['data'][] = intval($r['SUM(sales_raport_all.saldo_sprzedazy)']);
}

$json = array();
array_push($json,$result);
print json_encode($json);

?>
```

JSON give me:

```
[{"name":["2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-01"],"category":["IN","KD","\u0141S","NN","SG","TD"],"data":[2580,5030,12628,400,12979,15096]}]
```

Series looks greate but i dont know how to change category as in example **http://jsfiddle.net/rubJS/**

Comment: our json formatting is not correct

Comment: and what is correct format? i saw this format in one example :(

Comment: the format should be an array without the quotation marks

Comment: did You have any working example - i saw only one on [blueflame-software.com](http://blueflame-software.com/blog/column-chart-with-data-from-mysql-using-highcharts/)

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it in javascript. In other words, instead of defining variable for each `<x,y>` pair, return the data and let javascript construct the series. 
For example, given your current output you can prepare X and Y values (in javascript) in separate arrays and write a function pushing these values into series. It can be done like this (using jQuery as an example):

```
function build_chart(x_values, y_values, options)
{
   jQuery.each(x_values, function(item) {
        options.xAxis.categories.push(x_values[item]);
    });

    var series = {
        data: []
    };

    jQuery.each(y_values, function(item) {
        series.data.push(parseInt(y_values[item]));
    });

    options.series.push(series);
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

    return chart;

}
```

Where variable `options` defines a chart template without `series` member (which is added by the above function)

**EDIT**

Following the edit in the question, here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexpert/29TrY/1/) supporting it.
Note that the data in JSON is represented as array of arrays. First element in each array corresponds to the first category, second element in each array corresponds to the second category etc.

Comment: but first of {"name":"Date","data":["2014-01-01"]} is a category - not a series.

Comment: You can prepare your data according to category, i.e. following your example: `[{ "category" : {"name":"Date","data":["2014-01-01"]}, "series" : [{"name":"IN","data":[2580]},{"name":"KD","data":[5030]},{"name":"\u0141S","data":[12628]}] }, { "category" : { "name" : "Date", "data" : ["2014-01-02"]}, "series" : [ {"name" : "IN", "data" : [1234]} ] }];`.

Comment: this is what i search, but how add this to the JSON encoding?

Comment: Can You look at EDIT section? any suggestions?

Comment: I have updated my answer with jsFiddle. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from incorrect json format (which was mentioed) you need to push your dates as categorries in highcharts or use datetime type of axis, and then parse your date to timestamp.

Comment: i look everywhere... can anybody show me a good example how to properly encode this? im newbie.

Comment: I change JSON to `[{"name":"Data","data":["2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-01"]},{"name":"SG","data":[2580,5030,12628,400,12979,15096]},{"name":"KD","data":[1660,3333,9582,732,9034,11189]},{"name":"IN","data":[920,1697,3046,-332,3945,3906]}]` is this is correct? i look on this example [highcharts.com](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic), but how to implement this data?

Comment: How you parse this json? Because in array data with elements like "2014-01-01" shouldn't be used in series object.

Comment: I mean how you parse your json in javascirpt in highcharts, not how you create. Do you use this [{"name":"Data","data":["2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2014-01-01","20‌​14-01-01","2014-01-01"]},{"name":"SG","data":[2580,5030,12628,400,12979,15096]},{‌​"name":"KD","data":[1660,3333,9582,732,9034,11189]},{"name":"IN","data":[920,1697‌​,3046,-332,3945,3906]}] as series object?

Comment: I suggested this tutorial: [http://blueflame-software.com/blog/column-chart-with-data-from-mysql-using-highcharts/](http://blueflame-software.com/blog/column-chart-with-data-from-mysql-using-highcharts/)

Comment: I run your example and as I see in your JSON you have only three sereis, but in your parsing script (fiddle) you use i.e json[5] or json[10] object which doesn't exist in JSON, so you push undefined objects, as a result chart is not displayed. In case when you comment lines from chart3Options.series[3] = json[4] to chart3Options.series[10] = json[11] you will notice the difference.

Comment: yes, i agree, but i search a way to do this in flexible way-sometimes i have 1 data in series, sometimes i have 20 - it is possible?

Comment: Please look at EDIT segment for my question - any idea?

Comment: Obviously you can use loop and check length of json objects inside.